# Ionic Framework Global Variable

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am working on a geolocation, google maps project. I wrote a simple API and uploaded my server. I can reach my api's data with;

```
export class Tab2Page implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {
getLat: any;
getLong: any;
        constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation, public http: HttpClient) {
        this.http.get("apilink").subscribe(data => 
        {
          this.getLat = data["lat"];
          this.getLong = data["long"];
        });
       console.log(this.getLat); //gives undefined
      }
}
```

But when i want to reach getLat and getLong variable from any function - or outside this.http.get()- that variables give undefined. What should i do? I tried static, const, global, var declare etc.

```
ngAfterContentInit(): void {
console.log(this.getLat); //gives undefined
}
```

Comment: it is because data["lat"] does not exist

Comment: @ArunKumarMN console.log(data["lat"]); is working. => //41.097792

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that initially `getLat` and `getLong` are both null which gives `undefined` because you've not assigned them any value.

**Why this works inside subscribe?**

It is because when response from HTTP request is returned. Both the variable are assigned values using

```
this.getLat = data["lat"];
this.getLong = data["long"];
```

**Why this doesn't work outside subscribe?**

This is because the code inside `subscribe` is asynchronous i.e. it will run outside the normal execution of program and will run only when your HTTP request returns a response. As the HTTP request takes some time to complete and your `console.log` is executed first, so the result is `undefined`

**What you can do?**

If you want to execute a piece of code which requires the values of `getLat` and `getLong`, you can call that function inside the `subscribe` method or if you need these values outside your component,
You can create a [`Subject`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subject), then in your `subscribe` you send data to this `Subject` and then in your code you can `subscribe` to it

Answer (score 0):

It happens due to Async Request..

```
this.http.get("apilink").subscribe(data => // this started to execute but due to async request it will update once you get confirmation.
{
 this.getLat = data["lat"];
 this.getLong = data["long"];
});
console.log(this.getLat); //gives undefined (This executed before request return)
```

Your HTTP request just started to execute but before it completes console started to execute reason is, your **http request** was async..

so make sure it is sync or use `$.when $.then` call your console inside `$(then)`

Comment: Yeah, it is main problem. Thank you so much but i didn't fix the problem. I tried: put a button, when i click the button it works, variable getLat gives a number.(y)

I didn't find any solution how can i -sync- request?

Comment: I want to get data from my json and add the getLat variable. I will use in any function.